# Android SDK fails to find Java

Tags: java, android, java-8, android-sdk-manager

I have Java 8 update 25 installed with JDK 8.25. My problem is when I try to install the Android SDK tools, it gives me an error "..can't write in file java_find.exe" which I automatically understood as it can't find Java on my computer.

I have these two in my path variable:

```
C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_25/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_25/bin
```

What's wrong? The first time I installed the SDK tools, the SDK manager worked fine but now it just opens the command prompt and closes quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Check if u've got the JAVA_HOME environment variable. Check if the bin folder of your java installation is in the path and even if it is already there, move it to be the first one of the line.

It should work.

Comment: What should I put as a value for JAVA_HOME?

Comment: Path to the jdk... Mmh... It's the whole thing but the \bin

Comment: In the system PATH u have to have the bin. For windows users it is something like %JAVA_HOME%\bin but i'm not sure (but drunk) if there must be one or two % symbols, u better google for that

Comment: Another problem came out, after I fixed the SDK installing problem, now the manager won't launch the second time. At first it used to work properly and now it doesn't. What's the problem?

Comment: It may be that the manager wont't run with the RE you've installed

Comment: But the JDK automatically installs the jRE 1.8_25.. Should i get an older version?

Comment: Well... I'm usin java 7 with no problems ATALL... But it does not mean you're wrong for I just donno if you're running  the tool with jdk or jre or if the 8th one is not compatible :( sorry

Comment: Could you try to run the thing from a cmd window and see the error??

Comment: Btw... For as fast as i know the jdk7 is a release and 8 and  latter are official but not releases as we understand them for production. Sorry, i'm a j2ee developer and my customers won't give a damn for the thing until years from now :(. I'm stuck with older releases

Answer (score 0):

Add a system variable named JAVA_HOME and set it to C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_25